# Arquivos duplicados porém diferentes

Tags: android, android-studio

Bom, está ocorrendo um erro na minha aplicação pelo Android Studio. E o problema é que, a interface diz que existem dois arquivos que estão duplicados, porém eles são aparentemente diferentes. Também ja tentei deletá-los, porém, ao apagar o File1, aparecem erros de dependência no programa. Ao apagar a File2, ela retorna ao compilar o programa. Alguém pode me ajudar?

<kbd>[image: Erro]</kbd>

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
>   copied in APK org/apache/http/version.properties
>
> File1:
>   C:\Users\xxx.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrap‌​ped\org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client\4.1.2\98c86e42679fe7ac06‌​6f6c242e0d14f0bce0bb7c\org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client-4.1.2‌​.jar
>
> File2:
>   C:\Users\xxx.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\‌​httpcore\4.4.5\e7501a1b34325abb00d17dde96150604a0658b54\httpcore-4.4.5.jar

Comment: Sim realmente parecem diferentes, esse erro acontece ao compilar o seu projeto no Android Studio?

Comment: Isso, só aparece quando compila.

Comment: Consegui resolver. Ao invés de tentar deletar o .jar do File2, eu apenas tirei ele das dependências de biblioteca e ele parou de reaparecer ao compilar, não duplicando nada(mesmo sendo diferente) hehe. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @JerryMoon seria interessante postar isso como resposta então. Pode até mesmo aceitar sua resposta, qualquer coisa veja o [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver o problema bastou apenas tirar o .jar das dependências que meu programa não estava utilizando e funcionou. Obrigado a todos novamente.